# Faster way to communicate than FtpPutFile() needed

Tags: c, winapi, ftp, streaming

I have been asked to make a system where you have a "master" PC in which keys are typed and multiple "slave" PCs connected over the internet which need to receive those same keys as they are typed. My idea was that on the master pc, after each keypress I would write a tiny file to an ftp site containing the key number and the slave PCs would all be continuously reading that file. The system works but the writing is just a bit too slow and can't keep up with the speed of typing.

My code starts with `InternetOpen()` and `InternetConnect()` and then enters a loop reading keys and doing `FtpPutFile()`. It is the `FtpPutFile()` that is too slow despite the fact that the file is tiny.

I wonder if there's any way I can communicate with the slaves faster. For example by making use of "streaming"? I've never used streaming before and I'm not at all sure that it can be applied to my needs.

**EDIT:** Looking at the comments, maybe streaming was the wrong phrase, maybe what I need is a [persistent connection](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/persistent-connection-HTTP-persistent-connection)?

**EDIT:** Based on the comments, I have decided to use a cloud (Azure) PC as my master and write files directly to the servers webspace.

Comment: *"Streaming"* is not a technology. It's a fuzzy term to describe the process of continuously transferring data in a (semi-)realtime fashion.

Comment: Why use an ftp site? Can't the other PCs talk directly to the one holding the keys?

Comment: Your question assumes that the reason for the time required to transfer the file is somehow due to the overhead of `ftp`, rather than the network itself. The reason I bring this up is that the usual typing speed of a human is tens of keys per second, and `ftp` can generally transfer hundreds of small files per second over a persistent connection. First, are you using a persistent connection, or does every transfer re-connect? Second, have you checked latency between your machines? Specially when every transfer uses a new conn., the round-trip time might become important to system throughput.

Comment: @TSG: re:persistent connection, I am doing the InternetOpen() and InternetConnect() just once and then doing repeated calls to FtpPutFile()... doesn't that correspond to a persistent connection?

Comment: @4386427: are you suggesting I make the master into a server?

Comment: @Mick yes, cut out the middleman

Comment: I agree with 4386427... Just get rid of the ftp server, and while you're at it get rid of the `FTP` protocol as well. For this use case, a bunch of raw `TCP` connections is more than sufficient (as you don't really want to transfer files). The only downside is that the slaves need to know the IP address of the master, which is not necessary when using an additional server.

Comment: @Mick If the other PCs can "see" the one holding the keys there are plenty of free and fast server software on net that you can install. Then all you need is write some code that feeds key-data to the local server.

Comment: @4386427: I will certainly consider the server route - my concerns are A) security and B) permission from ISPs C) having to change a bunch of settings on routers... I will have to do this once on my PC during development and then all over again for my client... All doable I guess but I am hoping for an easier option.

Comment: If you can dig up enough information, you could certainly use [DCOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/com-dcom-and-type-libraries) for this. It allows you to implement a server without having to deal with all the networking. And it can be secured. Though it's ancient, and developers that can provide help are all but extinct.

Comment: @Mick "*doesn't that correspond to a persistent connection?*" - the FTP protocol uses multiple TCP connections. Only the main command TCP connection is "persistent".  Individual file transfers use secondary TCP connections.

Comment: @Remy: are you suggesting the master and slave PCs read/write data to the server directly using TCP? Is that possible?

Comment: @Mick sure it is possible. You would just have to write your own protocol for that. Not very hard. Have each slave make 1 connection to the master. When a slave connects, if keys have already been entered, send them to that slave immediately. And then, on each key press, the master can broadcast the latest keys (or even just the latest key press) to all connected clients.

Comment: @Remy: Correct me if I'm wrong but I get the feeling that TCP is a way of communicating where both ends are cooperating... so writing my own code to send a file to a generic third party server would not be possible... or are you are suggesting I communicate directly from master to slave without a server in between?

Comment: @Mick that is exactly what I'm suggesting. Write your own master and slave codes (you have to do that anyway, to make them understand what a key is to begin with) and make them communicate directly. Why do you think you need another server in between them?

Comment: @Remy: if there is a server in between then I don't have to convert any master or slave into a server... Or are you telling me I can communicate from master to slave with neither being set up as a server?

Comment: @Mick why don't you want to make the master act as a server?

Comment: @Remy: I gave the reasons in earlier comments... but now have decided to get a cloud based PC to use as a server so that should do the job.